# Display data from mysql database in php to then use in a vb.net application

Tags: php, mysql, database, vb.net, datagridview

Hi there okay so my goal is to get the information/data from my MySQL database and display it in my vb.net windows application. From the little I know, may be wrong but I don't think I should use the mysql connection straight from vb.net as this application will be used on multiple computers and networks which I will not have access to, plus they will not have static IP addresses. So I would like to know the best way to go about using PHP as the direct connection to the database and therefore the best way to output the data using PHP (maybe json format?) and to then use that within the vb.net application to populate a datagridview.

Thanks for any help..

Comment: If your vb.net code hasn't got access to the database then php certainly won't have access.

Comment: Sorry I might not have explained myself properly I have full access to the server through PHP and can get a connection the PHP will be run on the same server as the the database is located so no problem there! I want to use the php as an API as such to get the data required?

Comment: This would be the same situation i was in yet this example is using C#?http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609027/Displaying-JSON-from-PHP-into-a-DataGridView-using

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into the SSH functions of php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php